# Accessing app navigation or stack navigator's state from a non-component class

Tags: react-native

I have a React Native app with a non-component class (which does not extend Component or React.Component) that handles WebSocket (producer and consumer) connections. I instantiate this WebSocket as a singleton and use everywhere. What I am having trouble with, is how to access the 'app navigation' or the 'StackNavigator state' from this non-component class? This is to open a global modal to show the incoming data.

Based on the different ideas, the answer to any one of the following solves the problem:

1. How to access the app's navigation from a non-component class, to be able to do navigation.navigate?

OR

2. How to access state for the stack navigator (that shows modal based on a boolean in state) from a non-component class?

OR

3. How to store navigation (or state) for a component in a global variable to be accessed from a non-component class?

Anything more simpler is appreciated. Because this is the only case where I want to do something globally, I prefer not using any other state management tools/libraries.

My **WebSocket.js** looks something like:

```
import ReconnectingWebSocket from 'react-native-reconnecting-websocket';
import base64 from 'react-native-base64';

let instance = null;
const BROKER_SERVICE_URL = '192.168.43.111';

class WebSockets {
    if (!instance) {
      instance = this;
    }
    this.getNowAsDateTime = () => {
      let now = new Date();
      return (
        now.getUTCFullYear() +
        ('0' + (now.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
        ('0' + now.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) +
        ('0' + now.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) +
        ('0' + now.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) +
        ('0' + now.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2)
      );
    };
    
    // A property for testing the singleton
    this.creationDateTime = this.getNowAsDateTime();
    
    this.producer = new ReconnectingWebSocket(
      'ws://' +
        BROKER_SERVICE_URL +
        ':8080/ws/v2/producer/persistent/public/default/' +
        'mesosphere-router-input?compressionType=ZLIB',
      null,
      {
        reconnectInterval: 1000,
        maxReconnectInterval: 10000,
        reconnectDecay: 3,
        timeoutInterval: 5000,
        maxReconnectAttempts: null,
      },
    );
    let producerHeartCheck = {
      timeout: 55000, //default 10s
      timeoutObj: null,
      serverTimeoutObj: null,
      reset: function () {
        clearTimeout(this.timeoutObj);
        clearTimeout(this.serverTimeoutObj);
        return this;
      },
      start: function () {
        // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-this
        let self = this;
        this.timeoutObj = setTimeout(function () {
          console.log(
            'PRODUCER SOCKET',
            SEPARATOR,
            'producerHeartCheck.reset().start() SENDING pingRequest \n',
          );
          let jsonToSend = JSON.stringify({
            pingRequest: {
              workerId: 1,
              status: global.presence,
              requestedOn: instance.getNowAsDateTime(),
            },
          });
          instance.producer.send(
            JSON.stringify({
              payload: base64.encode(jsonToSend),
            }),
          );
          self.serverTimeoutObj = setTimeout(function () {
            instance.producer.close();
          }, self.timeout);
        }, this.timeout);
      },
    };
    this.producer.onopen = (event) => {
      producerHeartCheck.reset().start();
    };
    this.producer.onmessage = (event) => {
      producerHeartCheck.reset().start();
    };
    this.producer.onerror = (event) => {
      this.producer.close();
    };
    this.producer.onclose = (event) => {
      this.producer.reconnect();
    };
    
    this.consumer = new ReconnectingWebSocket(
      'ws://' +
        BROKER_SERVICE_URL +
        ':8080/ws/v2/consumer/persistent/public/default/' +
        'worker-1/WorkerId-' +
        this.getNowAsDateTime() +
        '?subscriptionType=Exclusive&consumerName=userID-' +
        this.getNowAsDateTime() +
        '',
      null,
      {
        reconnectInterval: 1000,
        maxReconnectInterval: 10000,
        reconnectDecay: 3,
        timeoutInterval: 5000,
        maxReconnectAttempts: null,
      },
    );
    let consumerHeartCheck = {
      timeout: 60000, //default 10s
      timeoutObj: null,
      serverTimeoutObj: null,
      reset: function () {
        clearTimeout(this.timeoutObj);
        clearTimeout(this.serverTimeoutObj);
        return this;
      },
      start: function () {
        // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-this
        let self = this;
        this.timeoutObj = setTimeout(function () {
          // Do nothing?
          self.serverTimeoutObj = setTimeout(function () {
            instance.consumer.close();
          }, self.timeout);
        }, this.timeout);
      },
    };
    this.consumer.onopen = (event) => {
      consumerHeartCheck.reset().start();
    };
    this.consumer.onmessage = (event) => {
      consumerHeartCheck.reset().start();
      const MESSAGE = JSON.parse(event.data);
      const MESSAGE_ID = MESSAGE.messageId;
      const MESSAGE_BODY = base64.decode(MESSAGE.payload);
      // Get MESSAGE_BODY as JSON
      const messageAsJson = JSON.parse(MESSAGE_BODY);

      // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO SHOW THE MESSAGE BODY IN THE MODAL 
      // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO SHOW THE MESSAGE BODY IN THE MODAL 
      // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO SHOW THE MESSAGE BODY IN THE MODAL 

      // Send acknowledgement for the received message
      this.consumer.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          messageId: MESSAGE_ID,
        }),
      );
    };
    this.consumer.onerror = (event) => {
      this.consumer.close();
    };
    this.consumer.onclose = (event) => {
      this.consumer.reconnect();
    };
    return instance;
}

export default WebSockets;
```

And here is my **Navigation.js** that has the model to be shown:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  Linking,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerItem,
  DrawerItemList,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import styles from './styles/navigation-styles';
import AboutScreen from './screens/AboutScreen';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import Login from './screens/Login';
import NotificationsScreen from './screens/NotificationsScreen';
import Signup from './screens/Signup';
import UserDetailsScreen from './screens/UserDetailsScreen';
import Modal from './Modal';

const DrawerMenu = (props) => (
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.drawerMenuSafeAreaView}>
    <TouchableHighlight
      onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('User Details')}>
      <View style={styles.drawerMenuView}>
        <Image
          source={require('./images/user.png')}
          style={styles.drawerMenuImage}
        />
        <View style={styles.drawerMenuText}>
          <Text style={styles.drawerName}>Name</Text>
          <Text style={styles.drawerMobileNumber}>0123456789</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    <ScrollView>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem
        label="Google"
        onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://google.com')}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
);
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function LeftDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      drawerBackgroundColor="grey"
      drawerPosition="left"
      drawerWidth="250"
      drawerType="slide"
      drawerContentOptions={{
        activeTintColor: 'red',
        inactiveTintColor: 'black',
        activeBackgroundColor: 'white',
      }}
      drawerContent={(navigation) => <DrawerMenu {...navigation} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
            <Image
              source={require('./icons/home.png')}
              style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="About"
        component={AboutScreen}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
            <Image
              source={require('./icons/about.png')}
              style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Logout"
        component={Login}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
            <Image
              source={require('./icons/logout.png')}
              style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const MainStack = (props) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="OfferModal"
        component={Modal}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          animationEnabled: true,
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="SignUp"
        component={Signup}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Login"
        component={Login}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="User Details"
        component={UserDetailsScreen}
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'User Details',
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={LeftDrawer}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={NotificationsScreen}
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Notifications',
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

function AppContainer() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MainStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default AppContainer;
```

And my **Modal.js** is:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default ({navigation}) => (
  <View
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }}>
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{backgroundColor: 'white', padding: 20}}
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>
      <Text>Let's go to HOME</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: how about you pass in the navigation prop as a callback?

Comment: You can expose a public function of the singleton class that accepts navigation as a parameter and saves it in the class property. You can provide navigation instance from the top-level stack I guess, based on your setup.

Comment: @WenW - Pass navigation prop as a callback? A short example will be helpful.

Comment: @SaachiTech - An example will be a lot of help. That was the question, how does a non-component class get navigation?

Comment: Could you please post your WebSocket class and your navigation stack, just a snippet so I can provide an example based on that?

Comment: @SaachiTech - Thanks in advance for the time to look into it. I have updated the question with the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the approaches could be as below.

Inside WebSocket.js create a function that accepts a navigation property and save it to the class for example

```
this.navigation = navigation => {
 if(!navigation) return this.navigation;
 this.navigation = navigation ;
}
```

In one of your Stack screen import WebSocket class and set the navigation in useEffect or componentDidMount

```
useEffect(()=>{
  ...
  WebSocket.navigation(props.navigation);
},[])

...

componentDidMount(){
  ...
  WebSocket.navigation(this.props.navigation);
}
```

Now your WebSocket class has an instance of the navigation and from there you should be able to navigate inside any of WebSocket function as below

```
this.navigation()?.navigate('my-modal')
```

I couldn't test this but should work

Comment: this should work. One thing I would like to add is the navigateTo prop. Since you don't know where the calling class would want to go within the websocket class. Or just accept the whole navigation.navigate(navigateTo) as a function within the websocket class.

Comment: May be send an object to navigation function with your desired props

Comment: Thanks a lot @SaachiTech. Your answer fully solved the problem. For the last line of code, I just had to use instance.navigation.navigate('my-modal'), because I had 'this' named to 'instance'.